# Are continuous variables for detection and categorical for density estimations?

Tags: r, distance, unmarked-package

This is probably a very basic yes or no question, I’m not very clued up with statistical analysis and R. I am doing a distance sampling analysis using unmarked. For the function distsamp(~1~1, umf) , I understand that the first ~1 should be a detection covariates and the second ~1 should be a density covariate. Am I correct to think that categorical variables are for density, whilst continuous or discrete variables are for detection?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but anyway it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com, or the r-help mailing list.

Comment: I don't know anything about this function, but I don't think so. Looking at the examples on the `?distsamp` help page, one example is `fm1jay <- distsamp(~chaparral ~chaparral, jayumf)`, using the same variable for both detection and density. If you can use the same variable for both, it doesn't seem like one must be continuous and one must be discrete.